# Variance of absolute value of a rv

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, variance

Suppose that $X \backsim iid (\mu, \sigma^2)$.  We are interested in $E (|X|)$ and ${\rm Var}(|X|)$.

Can you suggest a way to proceed?

I thought of rewriting $|X|$ as : $|X| =  Xd - X(1-d)$, where $d$ is a binary variable taking value of 1 if $X \geq 0$.

Of course if $X$ is normal, we have an answer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution), but I was looking for a more general case.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Because you are vague about the distribution, it sounds like you are looking to apply the definitions of expectation and variance--which of course have been amply illustrated and discussed in thousands of threads here. What specifically are you looking for beyond such generalities?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general calculation for both quantities can be obtained by the
application of [LOTUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).  For $\operatorname{var}(|X|)$,
note that
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(|X|) &= E[|X|^2] - \left(E[|X|]\right)^2\\
&= E[X^2] - \left(E[|X|]\right)^2\\&= \operatorname{var}(X) + \left(E[X]\right)^2- \left(E[|X|]\right)^2
\end{align}$$
and so only $E[|X|]$ might need to be *computed* if you already know $\operatorname{var}(X)$ and $E[X]$.